# Adding item to middle of ListView

Tags: java, android, android-listview

Right now, I am using this code to add an item to a listView:

```
SimpleAdapter adapter;
List<HashMap<String, String>> painItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
ListView listthings;
int[] to;
String[] from;

private void addItem() {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    //put stuff in the map here.
    painItems.add(map);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

I was wondering if I would be able to add an item to the list at a certain position rather than at the end of the list. This seems like something that shouldn't be too hard, but I may be missing something fundamental.

Thanks for your help, and cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `painItems.add(index, map);`

where index is the location you want to add the element at. All elements will be shifted one position to where their new index will be index + 1.

You have to be careful as this method will throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if the index is greater than the current size.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add(int,%20E)

Answer (score 1):

Yes just use the overloaded version of add:

```
myList.add(myPosition, myItem)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I like that you are being specific to android itself. Very concise!